# Nuget gives the error "ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, nuget

I have a new empty MVC 5 project, and I try to install Nuget packages. 
When I insert in the Nuget Console the command :Update-Package I got the following asnwer:

```
File E:\WebApp\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\uninstall.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.At line:1 char:3
+ & 'E:\WebApp\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.Dot ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

then I start to install some new packages and got again this message:

**WebApp\packages\Modernizr.2.8.3\tools\install.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system**

I saw some posts related with this message, but not related with MVC projects.

My question is:

Why I get those messages?

What can I do to fix this issue?

This issue, can appear on the server where my application will run? Some scripts to not run as expected?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I guess the specific package you are trying to install needs to run a Powershell script and for some reason, Powershell execution is disabled on your machine. 
You can search google on "how to enable Powershell" for a complete guide but generally, it goes like this:

- Open up a Powershell command window (just search for Powershell after pressing windows start button)
- Check out current restrictions by typing `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
- Enable PowerShell by typing `Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned`

This issue does not affect the server you are planing to install your application on.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Same here, solution did not work for me. Any idea hot to tackle this?

Comment: Running VS as administrator worked for me. Same issue as Rosdi above.

Comment: I had to run PowerShell (x86) version in order for VS to pick up the new policy.

Answer (score 10):

In case anybody finds this on Google and this happened to you, I suggest you first try restarting Visual Studio, particularly if the Package Manager Console has worked for you before.  In VS 2019, I've noticed that, if I leave it in the background while it's loading, sometimes it'll throw that error.

For me, **restarting Visual Studio and leaving it in the foreground until the Package Manager Console finished initializing solved the issue**.  Note that running it as administrator was not necessary.

Comment: All my powershell settings showed "unrestricted" but got the error message anyway. Restarting Visual Studio solved it.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you encounter this installing NuGet packages from Visual Studio Package Manager Console, run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: If you run as Administrator and type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in Package Manager Console, you get `RemoteSigned`. If you just run Visual Studio not as Administrator, you get `Restricted` for `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. And because it is Restricted, you cannot run scripts. Re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core#restricted

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Translation of the image text would be somewhat: This certificate has been **revoked** from its key store.

Certificate on my init.ps1 has expired - thus `RemoteSigned` will not do. For that package version to work, it would need to be set to `ByPass` or `Unrestricted`. Personally, i would not recommend doing this...

-- EDIT --
I went ahead and updated the package and found they have resigned a new cert for v 1.0.2. Issue following in NuGet console for fix:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: I got the above error on Windows 7 Pro, following Entrodus advice I manage to fix the issue. Now I am using Windows 10 and I had no similar issue.

Comment: Updating the package solved my issue on VS2015 at Win10 as well. Thanks.

Comment: Was getting this error on VS2017 in Windows 10, running VS as admin, execution policy Unrestricted... this fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

open your power-shell as administration and type

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

Expected result RemoteSigned

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

**if it does not work, try Powershell run in administrator**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue building a project and found that you MAY have to set the execution policy to remoteSigned (as others have mentioned) in BOTH powershell (x86) and powershell (x64).  I was running the x64 version as administrator and Get-ExecutionPolicy returned "remoteSigned" but the x86 version hadn't been updated.  Just something to try if the above answers don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

open your power-shell as administration and type

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

Expected result `RemoteSigned`

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

**Enjoy**

Answer (score 0):

A quick to fix this error when using Package Manager Console without VS restart and/or running as Admin is to remove the restriction for current user:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -scope CurrentUser
```