# How to execute the start script with Nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

How can I execute the start script from a *package.json* file with Nodemon?

Comment: You sure you can execute a start script from package.json? Because from what I know package.json is to list all your dependencies and nodemon is to keep your process running. I am not quite sure what you are hinting at here?

Answer (score 209):

This will be a simple command for this

```
nodemon --exec npm start
```

Comment: What if I need to run only tests without running the app? You solution runs both.

Comment: this does run `npm start` but does not start the node server for me..  how would it know where server.js is ?

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. It is up to the user to make sure their NPM scripts actually do what they want them to. You can use nodemon directly in your scripts, but that's not what was asked. This is the proper way to have nodemon rerun scripts on changes.

Answer (score 75):

In package json:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my server",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon my_file.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "~1.3.8",
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

Then from the terminal you can use `npm start`

Nodemon installation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: Sorry, looking for a way to execute the start script _with_ nodemon, not execute nodemon in the start script. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Won't `npm start` fail in production for lack of nodemon?

Comment: `npm run start` not `npm start`

Comment: I'm a beginner with npm. I don't understand why do we need to specify the start script while we can use nodemon out of the box? I just install nodemon with npm and use it directly without specifying any script and it works perfectly.

Comment: @M.Dhaouadi `npm start` is an alias for `npm run start`

Comment: ````nodemon yourfile.js```` directly from the terminal

Answer (score 32):

I have a TypeScript file called "server.ts", The following npm scripts configures Nodemon and npm to start my app and monitor for any changes on TypeScript files:

```
"start": "nodemon -e ts  --exec \"npm run myapp\"",
"myapp": "tsc -p . && node server.js",
```

I already have Nodemon on dependencies. When I run `npm start`, it will ask Nodemon to monitor its files using the `-e` switch and then it calls the `myapp` npm script which is a simple combination of transpiling the typescript files and then starting the resulting server.js. When I change the TypeScript file, because of `-e` switch the same cycle happens and new .js files will be generated and executed.

Answer (score 23):

I use Nodemon version 1.88.3 in my Node.js project.
To install Nodemon, see in https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon.

Check your package.json, see if "scripts" has changed like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

`server.js` is my file name, you can use another name for this file like `app.js`.

After that, run this on your terminal: `npm run dev`

Answer (score 15):

Use `-exec`:

```
"your-script-name": "nodemon [options] --exec 'npm start -s'"
```

Comment: Is there any way other than exec to do this?

Comment: Just `nodemon [options] --exec 'npm start -s'` if you want to do it from the command line.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Install it.

Comment: I have no idea about `-s` flag within `npm start -s`.

Comment: @liuliang It's a shortcut for `--loglevel silent` (it was just an example).

Answer (score 15):

In package `json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index",
  "dev": "nodemon index"
},

"devDependencies": {
  "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
}
```

And in the terminal for developing:

```
npm run dev
```

And for starting the server regularly:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 7):

First change your *package.json* file,

```
"scripts":
    { 
        "start": "node ./bin/www",
        "start-dev": "nodemon ./app.js"
    },
```

After that, execute command

```
npm run start-dev
```

Comment: But when you run off of `app.js` you are bypassing everything that `./bin/www` does...

Comment: this open new tab each time

Answer (score 7):

In package.json file. change file like this

```
"scripts":{ 
   "start": "node ./bin/www", 
   "start-dev": "nodemon ./app.js"
 },
```

and then execute **npm run start-dev**

Answer (score 5):

Add this to script object from your project's package.json file

```
    "start":"nodemon index.js"
```

It should be like this

```
    "scripts": {
        "start":"nodemon index.js"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Nodemon emits events upon every change in state; start, restart crash, etc. You can add a Nodemon configuration file (nodemon.json) like so:

```
{
   "events": {
       "start": "npm run *your_file*"
   }
}
```

Read more in *[Nodemon events — run tasks at server start, restart, crash, exit](https://medium.com/netscape/nodemon-events-run-tasks-at-server-start-restart-crash-exit-93a34c54dfd8)*.

Answer (score 4):

I simply use 'npx' in the terminal to set up nodemon and execute it

```
npx nodemon
```

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on types of your Nodemon installation. If you install Nodemon globally by using commands (`npm install nodemon --global` or `npm install nodemon -g`), you do not have to specify any script for Nodemon in your *package.json* file. Just executing command `nodemon index.js` will run your project.

But if you install Nodemon locally by command `npm install nodemon` then you have to specify the script. If you name it as **start** then `npm run start` or `npm start` will trigger the server to run.

```
// Absolutely no need for global installation
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If globally installed then

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon FileName.js(server.js)",
},
```

Make sure you have installed `nodemon` globally:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Finally, if you are a Windows user, make sure that [the security restriction of the Windows PowerShell is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692087/nuget-give-this-error-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled).

Comment: not true, for this to work, only add nodemon with dev dependencies will do, just that "nodemon" won't be available at your command line if you run it directly.

Answer (score 3):

To run `nodemon` and `ts-node` on your project,

```
npm install ts-node nodemon
```

Then create a file at root project where `package.json` is called `nodemon.json`:

```json
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```

The in `package.json` add the start script:

```json
{
  "name": "http_file_recieve_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

Finally start your project

```bash
npm run start
```

Make sure that at the root of your src folder you have a file called `index.ts` if thats what you defined your entry point in the `nodemon.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install nodemon globally for frequent use:

`npm i nodemon -g` or `sudo npm i nodemon -g`

then edit your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Generally, 'dev' specifies developmental use (**npm run dev**).

Answer (score 2):

First install package for `nodemon` as dev dependencies using

```
$ npm i nodemon -D
```

Then your `package.json` will have:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
```

Then you can edit change `package.json` `scripts` part as

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  }
```

Then you can use command:

```
$ npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

{
"name": "backend",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.16.1",
"hbs": "^4.1.2",
"http-errors": "~1.6.3",
"morgan": "~1.9.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.12"
}
}

> use "nodemon ./bin/www" scripts > start

- eg:

> "scripts": {
> "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
> },

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with watch:

```
nodemon --exec ts-node pathtoapp/filewithserver.ts -e ts
```

my project example: `nodemon --exec ts-node src/server.ts -e ts`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a global install, add Nodemon as a dependency, then...

package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start-dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js ./bin/www"
  },
```

Comment: You can still make it "start-dev": "nodemon ./bin/www" if you install it under devDependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you have `nodemon` installed globally, simply running `nodemon` in your project will automatically run the `start` script from `package.json`.

For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node src/server.js"
},
```

From [the nodemon documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage):

> nodemon will also search for the scripts.start property in package.json (as of nodemon 1.1.x).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 5 years late, if you want to use `nodemon.json` you may try this,

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": ["*.test.js", "fixtures/*"],
  "execMap": {
    "js": "electron ." // 'js' is for the extension, and 'electron .' is command that I want to execute
  }
}
```

The `execMap` will execute like a `script` in package.json, then you can run `nodemon js`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of npm start :

```
npx env-cmd nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one:

```
nodemon --exec ts-node src/app.ts
```

This will run the `app.ts` for you forever

Answer (score 0):

You can also install nodemon as a development dependency:

`npm install --save-dev nodemon` or using yarn: `yarn add nodemon -D`.

With a local installation, nodemon will not be available in your system path or you can't use it directly from the command line. Instead, the local installation of nodemon can be run by calling it from within an npm script (such as `npm start`) or using `npx nodemon`.

In other words just run it with `npx nodemon index.js`

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way

```
{
  "name": "cyber",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/app.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"start": "node app.ts"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the command : **`npx nodemon app.js`**

This is very simple ! and we can run the below command without altering the package.json file in your project